# "TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" while sorting pandas dataframe index

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe `h`:

```
In [24]: h.head()
Out[24]: 
                 alpha1  alpha2    gamma1  gamma2       chi2min gender  age
filename                                                                   
F35_HC_532d.dat  0.0000   0.000       NaN    0.00  1.000000e+25      F   35
M48_HC_551d.dat  0.7353   3.943  0.425922    0.15  2.072617e+01      M   48
M24_HC_458d.dat  0.7777   4.754  0.463753    0.15  1.390893e+01      M   24
M48_HC_552d.dat  0.7633   3.672  0.394370    0.15  1.965052e+01      M   48
M40_HC_506d.dat  0.7793   3.271  0.513597    0.20  1.089716e+01      M   40
```

I am trying to sort the dataframe index according to age values:

```
In [25]: h.sort_index(h.sort_values('age'))
```

This throws an error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you after: `h.sort_values('age')`? Can you provide a desired data set?

Comment: @MaxU : I think I didn't get you. I am trying to arrange the rows of the dataframe according to the `age` values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [14]: h
Out[14]:
                 alpha1  alpha2    gamma1  gamma2       chi2min gender  age
filename
F35_HC_532d.dat  0.0000   0.000       NaN    0.00  1.000000e+25      F   35
M48_HC_551d.dat  0.7353   3.943  0.425922    0.15  2.072617e+01      M   48
M24_HC_458d.dat  0.7777   4.754  0.463753    0.15  1.390893e+01      M   24
M48_HC_552d.dat  0.7633   3.672  0.394370    0.15  1.965052e+01      M   48
M40_HC_506d.dat  0.7793   3.271  0.513597    0.20  1.089716e+01      M   40

In [15]: h.sort_values('age')
Out[15]:
                 alpha1  alpha2    gamma1  gamma2       chi2min gender  age
filename
M24_HC_458d.dat  0.7777   4.754  0.463753    0.15  1.390893e+01      M   24
F35_HC_532d.dat  0.0000   0.000       NaN    0.00  1.000000e+25      F   35
M40_HC_506d.dat  0.7793   3.271  0.513597    0.20  1.089716e+01      M   40
M48_HC_551d.dat  0.7353   3.943  0.425922    0.15  2.072617e+01      M   48
M48_HC_552d.dat  0.7633   3.672  0.394370    0.15  1.965052e+01      M   48
```

Comment: I realized now. That's right. I was making a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think your index is filename. Maybe you could try something like:

```
h['index1'] = h.index
h.sort_values(by=['index1', 'age'])
```

But also it will not make so much sense since it will not change the order. Alternatively you can try:

```
h.sort_values(by='age')
```

Then:

```
h.reindex([range(some_number)])
```

Comment: That's another method. I want to know what is wrong with my method.

Comment: the problem in your method is indices are filenames not numbers