# TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

My Code:

```
samples = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data", sep=',',header=None)
varieties = pd.DataFrame(samples.iloc[:,0])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
labels = kmeans.fit_predict(samples)
#setting 'labels' according to given data
labels += 1
#converting 'labels' to pandas DataFrame
labels = pd.DataFrame(labels)
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels':[labels], 'varieties':[varieties]})
ct = pd.crosstab(df['labels'],df['varieties'])
```

I want to use these dataframes (labels and varieties) for 'crosstab' function.
Please do let me know how I can do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" while sorting pandas dataframe index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054217/typeerror-dataframe-objects-are-mutable-thus-they-cannot-be-hashed-while-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you storing the labels in a separate dataframe? Might be easier to save it just as a new column in the variaties dataframe, and then run crosstab between those two columns.

```
samples = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data", sep=',',header=None)
varieties = pd.DataFrame(samples.iloc[:,0])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
varieties['labels'] = kmeans.fit_predict(samples)
#setting 'labels' according to given data
varieties['labels'] += 1
pd.crosstab(varieties.iloc[:,0], varieties['labels'])
```

Comment: @0AJ0 feel free to upvote this too, if the answer was helpful