# Convert Dataframe column to resolve TypeError Cannot be hashed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This question has been asked many times on SO, but in every case I found the answer was always to change the OP's code to get the correct result a different way. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054217/typeerror-dataframe-objects-are-mutable-thus-they-cannot-be-hashed-while-s) [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239097/typeerror-dataframe-objects-are-mutable-thus-they-cannot-be-hashed/43239268)

Rather than using a different method to solve the problem, how do you convert a dataframe column to something that can be hashed? Or, if that is not possible, why do you have to use another method?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'name':['bil','bil','bil','jim'],
     'col2': ['acct','law', 'acct2','law'],
     'col3': [1,2,3,55],
     'col4': [1,1,1,2]

    }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
coursesFilter=['acct']

print(df2[df2['col2'].isin([coursesFilter])]) #TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
print(df2[df2['col2'].isin([pd.Series(coursesFilter)])]) #TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
print(df2[df2['col2'].isin([pd.Series(coursesFilter).tolist()])]) #TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need remove `[]`:

```
print(df2[df2['col2'].isin(coursesFilter)])
print(df2[df2['col2'].isin(pd.Series(coursesFilter))])
print(df2[df2['col2'].isin(pd.Series(coursesFilter).tolist())])
```

Input [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) parameters:

> values : set or list-like
>
> The sequence of values to test. Passing in a single string will raise a TypeError. Instead, turn a single string into a list of one element.

Answer (score 1):

Your coursesFilter already a list object , do not need add []

```
df2[df2['col2'].isin(coursesFilter)]
Out[410]: 
   col2  col3  col4 name
0  acct     1     1  bil
```